# getX router back navigation

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm using `GetX` package and I want to close and remove one dialog on my page.
Actually, I don't want to remove the snack bar or other things.
I just want to remove and close one special dialog.
Is there any way to do that?

This is my dialog with GetX package:

```
Get.dialog(
      Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: const [
          Center(
            child: Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(50.0),
              child: Center(
                child: Loading(),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      barrierDismissible: false,
    ),
```

And this is to remove my dialog:

```
  Get.back();
```

Comment: The Get.back() don't solve for your?

Comment: But it also destroys all other widgets like the snack bars, but I want it to destroy only this dialog.

Comment: Where you add the Get.back(); code?

Comment: In my controller

Comment: This dialog is only for loading and don't have buttons, ok?

Comment: Yes, this is for loading, and when I got a response, I want to close loading dialog

Comment: what about `Navigator.pop(context)`

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
if(Get.isDialogOpen){
Get.back();
}
else{
//whatever you want.
}
```

By using this you can close the dialog only without closing other widgets like snackbar our your route/widget.

Comment: Not true, because sometimes I was opening dialog and snack bar at the same time, and I want to close just dialog, but when calling the `Get.back()`, first closed snack bar

Comment: // check if snackbar is open
Get.isSnackbarOpen

There is a solution for that too.